# How to distinct same id with different column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Join the data from SQL server and Oracle using Union function but i have some trouble with the data. The Output show up with the same id and different column values.

I already tried Distinct & Group by but cant solve this issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT binusianid as ID,Name
FROM   (SELECT  binusian_id AS BinusianID, 
                        Upper(nama) AS NAME 
        FROM   hris.hris_db.dbo. master_data_pribadi_pegawai 
        WHERE  stsrc = 'A' 
        UNION 
        SELECT emplid, 
               first_name + ' ' + ( CASE 
                                      WHEN last_name = first_name THEN '' 
                                      ELSE last_name 
                                    END ) AS NAME 
        FROM   Openquery (oracle22, 
'select a.EMPLID,b.FIRST_NAME,b.LAST_NAME  from ps_n_lc_job_info a 
JOIN PS_NAMES b ON b.EMPLID = a.EMPLID 
WHERE a.N_ACTION_CODE NOT IN(''KELUAR'',''MENINGGAL'',''BATAL'',''DROPOUT'')' 
))a 
Group by a.BinusianID,Name
```

Output Sample is as below

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @TomC Union will give you distinct record of ID and Name. 
However the problem here is with the Data, The name returned from Oracle is different but the ID is same. Hence you will get two records with the same ID.

[image]

If you wish to eleminate any one of these you can use SQL `RowNumber()` function. 
I have created a Demo in SQL just to explain how it can be used in your case. 
I have added one more record to explain better.

[image]

Result - 
[image]

The result is same having duplicate rows. The another record which is same in both SQL and Oracle is returned unique by Union.

If you wish to eliminate any one use as below.

[image]

[**Demo**](https://rextester.com/RMXP20303)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need the group by, or the DISTINCT as you are performing a UNION which will automatically only return distinct rows.

Secondly, if you have the same ID in two different databases that have different users, then there is no way to make them distinct.

If the two are supposed to contain the same data then you have a data integrity issue.

If they can have overlapping primary keys then you need to add a DataSource column into your query do that they become unique on ID+Source, not just ID.